# Can nested route in rails app be a root url for Backbone.js app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I am trying to complete my first backbone app based on rails. Base webapp is used for managing tournaments( registrations, players, etc ).

So I have url like /tournaments/tournament_id/(players | registrations | results )

I want to create backbone app to handle managing course of particular tournament, specificaly: pairing, generating rounds changes removing and adding players on the fly. Backbone would make it fast, nice and userfriendly.

Also it's important to be able to handle multiple tournaments at the same time as the app should serve country league where tournaments in different cities happen at the same day.

So I would like to have backbone start on /tournaments/tournament_id/play . I don't have a problem to initialize it but the backbone actions are not working correctly. Index is looking for '/' url and rest of actions as well are triggered with .../../play/

How should my router look like to make it work?Is it possible with Backbone?

Ilooked for answers but all tutorials are about single page apps that are only build on rails server and not coexisting with pure rails webapp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish what you want by changing the way you start your app using `Backbone.history`.

```
Backbone.history.start({pushState : true, root : "/tournaments/<some-id>/play"});
```

Then all of your routes will be hanging off of that root.

http://backbonejs.org/#History-start